# Difference between $f(a)=b$ and $f:a\mapsto b$?

Tags: notation

From what I understand, these two notations are exactly the same. Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Basically yes. But in my experience the second version is more often used for the general definition as opposed to a single value. That is, $f:x\mapsto x^2$ is more normal than $f:2\mapsto 4$. Not a hard rule though

Comment: I would only use the second formulation to indicate the general form of the function.  Thus, with $f(x)=x^2$.   I would write $f: x\mapsto x^2$ but I would not write $f:0\mapsto 0$, though of course $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Also note that $\mapsto$ allows you to talk about a function without giving it a name: $x\mapsto x^2$ is a function even without the name $f$.

Comment: The two notations are obviously not exactly the same. But they mean the same.